# Vue js - reference variable in object

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I am new to vue and can't find a solution to this -

I have a JSON object here, and I am trying to dynamically fetch the **"info"** of a user based on their **"userRegion"**.

```
{
"userData": {
    "kr": {
      "info": {
        "name": "testing-123",
     }
    },
    "any": null,
    "us": null,
    "eu": {
      "info": {
        "name": "testing-456",
     }
    },
  },
   "userRegion": "eu" 
}
```

I then have this object in vue and I want to dynamically change region and pull the data from the object based on this region value in the "user" object below.

```
 user:{ 
        region:  this.userData.userRegion,
        name: this.userData[this.user.region].info.name
    },
```

For example, I have tried using something like this

```
this.userData.userData[this.user.region]
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'region' of undefined"
```

the variable I am using "userData" is passed down from the parent like so:

```
<infoWindow :userData='userData'></infoWindow>
```

and is set as a prop:

```
props: {
        userData: app.userData,
     },
```

any help would be aprpeciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t really understand where you are setting this `user`, whether its part of an initialized data object, or a computed property. However, there is a temporal issue there:

```
user: {
    region: this.userData.userRegion,
    name: this.userData[this.user.region].info.name
},
```

In order to set up `user.name`, `user.region` needs to be already there. But since you are creating the `user` object at once, this does not work. So you either have to split that up, or repeat the logic for the user region again:

```
user: {
    region: this.userData.userRegion,
    name: this.userData[this.userData.userRegion].info.name
},
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to explain it was from an api that returns the object! This worked perfectly though - thank you! And thanks for the explanation, it makes so much more sense now :)